# Unsupported ciphersuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

Tags: java, scala, ssl, spray

I recently received a certificate from Commodo and I'm trying to integrate it with my Scala Spray Server. I have an trait to configure my Spray sever:

```
import java.io.{BufferedInputStream, FileInputStream}
import java.security.{SecureRandom, KeyStore}
import java.security.cert.{X509Certificate, CertificateFactory}
import javax.net.ssl.{TrustManagerFactory, KeyManagerFactory, SSLContext}
import spray.io._
import org.apache.camel.util.jsse._

// for SSL support (if enabled in application.conf)
trait MySSLConfig {
  // if there is no SSLContext in scope implicitly the HttpServer uses the default SSLContext,
  // since we want non-default settings in this example we make a custom SSLContext available here
  implicit def sslContext: SSLContext = {
    val keyStoreResource = "/home/ubuntu/key.jks"
    val password = "password"

    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks")
    keyStore.load(getClass.getResourceAsStream(keyStoreResource), password.toCharArray)
    val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray)
    val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore)
    val context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers, new SecureRandom)
    context
  }
  implicit def sslEngineProvider: ServerSSLEngineProvider = {
    ServerSSLEngineProvider { engine =>
      engine.setEnabledCipherSuites(Array("TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"))
      engine.setEnabledProtocols(Array("SSLv3", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1"))
      engine
    }
  }
}
```

However I am getting this error at runtime when I try and request my uri with https

```
2015-09-15 02:06:54,662 - [ERROR] - from akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy in NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-11
Unsupported ciphersuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.valueOf(CipherSuite.java:235) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(CipherSuiteList.java:82) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLEngineImpl.java:2014) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.suredbits.dfs.config.MySSLConfig$$anonfun$sslEngineProvider$1.apply(MySslConfig.scala:34) ~[suredbits-dfs.suredbits-dfs-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at com.suredbits.dfs.config.MySSLConfig$$anonfun$sslEngineProvider$1.apply(MySslConfig.scala:33) ~[suredbits-dfs.suredbits-dfs-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.SSLEngineProviderCompanion$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(SslTlsSupport.scala:408) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.SSLEngineProviderCompanion$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(SslTlsSupport.scala:408) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.ServerSSLEngineProvider$$anon$3.apply(SslTlsSupport.scala:427) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.ServerSSLEngineProvider$$anon$3.apply(SslTlsSupport.scala:425) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection$$anon$1.sslEngine(HttpServerConnection.scala:78) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.can.server.RequestParsing$$anon$1$$anon$2.<init>(RequestParsing.scala:41) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.can.server.RequestParsing$$anon$1.apply(RequestParsing.scala:39) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.can.server.RequestParsing$$anon$1.apply(RequestParsing.scala:37) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3.apply(Pipelines.scala:117) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3.apply(Pipelines.scala:116) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3.apply(Pipelines.scala:116) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3.apply(Pipelines.scala:116) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3.apply(Pipelines.scala:116) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3.apply(Pipelines.scala:116) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.io.ConnectionHandler$class.running(ConnectionHandler.scala:56) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection.running(HttpServerConnection.scala:29) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection.register(HttpServerConnection.scala:68) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(HttpServerConnection.scala:49) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection.aroundReceive(HttpServerConnection.scala:29) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:254) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:221) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [suredbits-dfs-nfl-assembly-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
```

Can anyone provide any insight as to why I am getting this error?

EDIT:

I upgraded the jdk to 1.8 as @Steffen Ullrich which yields a new error that I am receiving:

```
2015-09-15 15:14:51,717 - [ERROR] - from spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection in NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7
Aborting encrypted connection to my-ip due to [SSLHandshakeException:no cipher suites in common] -> [SSLHandshakeException:no cipher suites in common]

2015-09-15 15:14:51,881 - [ERROR] - from spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection in NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Aborting encrypted connection to my-ip due to [SSLHandshakeException:no cipher suites in common] -> [SSLHandshakeException:no cipher suites in common]

2015-09-15 15:14:52,029 - [ERROR] - from spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection in NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10
Aborting encrypted connection to my-ip due to [SSLHandshakeException:Client requested protocol TLSv1.1 not enabled or not supported] -> [SSLHandshakeException:Client requested protocol TLSv1.1 not enabled or not supported]

2015-09-15 15:14:52,184 - [ERROR] - from spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection in NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
Aborting encrypted connection to my-ip due to [SSLHandshakeException:Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported] -> [SSLHandshakeException:Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported]
```

EDIT2:

I modified this line

```
engine.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslContext.getServerSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites)
```

which gives me a list of cipher suites that includes

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

however I am still getting this error:

```
2015-09-15 18:43:55,690 - [INFO] - from org.apache.camel.util.jsse.SSLContextParameters in NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9
Available providers: SUN version 1.8.

2015-09-15 18:43:55,696 - [ERROR] - from spray.can.server.HttpServerConnection in NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Aborting encrypted connection to my-ip due to [SSLHandshakeException:no cipher suites in common] -> [SSLHandshakeException:no cipher suites in common]
```

more logs using a more granular debugging mode for -Djava.net.debug=ssl

```
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-42, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 167
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: -265533514 bytes = { 61, 40, 108, 219, 248, 171, 159, 143, 197, 121, 120, 2, 169, 117, 206, 251, 77, 174, 188, 36, 13, 240, 239, 104, 177, 132, 36, 253 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x56:0x0, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=api.extrapoint.io]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Unsupported extension type_13172, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:12:08:73:70:64:79:2f:33:2e:31:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-868, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-42, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-868, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-42, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-42, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-42, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 167
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1569487286 bytes = { 25, 54, 227, 33, 169, 61, 202, 196, 56, 250, 139, 68, 8, 183, 153, 237, 234, 230, 40, 91, 244, 198, 29, 236, 243, 121, 109, 28 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x56:0x0, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=api.extrapoint.io]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Unsupported extension type_13172, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:12:08:73:70:64:79:2f:33:2e:31:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-869, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-869, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-45, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 167
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1995784349 bytes = { 231, 253, 51, 160, 51, 83, 215, 117, 136, 228, 2, 249, 107, 133, 172, 213, 70, 200, 95, 170, 53, 5, 93, 19, 131, 185, 241, 92 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x56:0x0, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=api.extrapoint.io]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Unsupported extension type_13172, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:12:08:73:70:64:79:2f:33:2e:31:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-870, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-45, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-870, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-45, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-45, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-45, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 208
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1327152795 bytes = { 83, 242, 3, 179, 176, 55, 11, 121, 181, 163, 83, 1, 237, 23, 101, 140, 177, 179, 40, 128, 77, 190, 63, 204, 162, 105, 4, 57 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=api.extrapoint.io]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Unsupported extension type_13172, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:1b:08:73:70:64:79:2f:33:2e:31:05:68:32:2d:31:34:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA256withRSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA512withECDSA, SHA1withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x4, signature:0x2), SHA1withDSA
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-871, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-871, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-43, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 167
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: -300410757 bytes = { 151, 231, 251, 170, 239, 146, 191, 87, 5, 9, 151, 64, 86, 10, 220, 175, 228, 71, 112, 41, 250, 35, 36, 140, 114, 28, 8, 130 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x56:0x0, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=api.extrapoint.io]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Unsupported extension type_13172, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:12:08:73:70:64:79:2f:33:2e:31:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-872, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-43, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-872, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-43, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-43, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-43, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-43, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 167
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.1
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1944581904 bytes = { 65, 211, 112, 212, 209, 223, 205, 60, 175, 177, 83, 168, 139, 174, 78, 221, 40, 69, 103, 105, 117, 231, 103, 50, 53, 237, 22, 58 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x56:0x0, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=api.extrapoint.io]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Unsupported extension type_13172, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:12:08:73:70:64:79:2f:33:2e:31:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-873, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-43, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-873, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-43, SEND TLSv1.1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-43, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Alert, length = 2
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-43, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 167
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 584450856 bytes = { 254, 198, 84, 40, 79, 119, 157, 34, 77, 19, 234, 180, 195, 251, 21, 69, 247, 233, 184, 117, 184, 4, 179, 104, 68, 102, 84, 232 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x56:0x0, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=api.extrapoint.io]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Unsupported extension type_13172, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:12:08:73:70:64:79:2f:33:2e:31:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-874, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-874, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this was that the key was generated incorrectly. I had to go on to support with COMODO and get help with the key generation.

Answer (score 2):

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 is a TLSv1.2 cipher suite.
It can not be used with SSLv3 or TLSv1. Also, it might not be even available for the *unknown* version of Java you are using.

Edit: since it is now known that Java 1.7 is used:

According to [the documentation from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) no GCM ciphers are available in Java 1.7 but they only got added to Java 1.8. Which explains the message about unsupported cipher.

Comment: I also tried adding `TLSv1.2` to the array of `enabledProtocols` and this did not work.

Comment: @ChrisStewart: Are you sure that you got an ECC certificate? The RSA certificates you get usually will not work with ECDSA suites. And is there are reason you want to use exactly this cipher suite and nothing else - since client support for this cipher is limited.

Comment: I looked at another site that I am using a similar cert on it and it said that the key exchange mechanism being used is ECDHE_ECDSA with AES_128_GCM as the encryption mechanism. I generated the SSL certs the same way however I am using them on different web frameworks.

Comment: @ChrisStewart: see edit. The cipher is not supported with your Java version.

Comment: Yes, I released this after you asked what jdk I was using. I upgraded to jdk to 1.8 and now I am getting a different error which I added to the OP

Comment: @ChrisStewart: now your server supports this cipher suite but it looks like your client don't.  If you want to use a cipher the client must offer it (which it does not) and the server then can accept the offer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89733/discussion-between-chris-stewart-and-steffen-ullrich).